# Order the array result using $percent variable php

Tags: php, foreach, sql-order-by

**This is my array:**

```
$mygetting_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT post_id,meta_value from wp_postmeta Where meta_value  LIKE '".$search_res[$k]."%' OR meta_value  LIKE '%".$search_res[$k]."%'  AND meta_key='my_profile_tags' ORDER BY post_id $limit");

    foreach ( $mygetting_id as $post )
    {
        $id = $post->post_id;

        $metaValue= esc_attr(get_post_meta($id, 'my_profile_tags',true));
        $array_metaValue = explode(',',$metaValue);
        $array_metaValue = array_map('strtolower', $array_metaValue);
        $total_tags=count($array_metaValue);//like total=10

        for($e=0;$e<=count($search_res);$e++)
        {
            $key = count( array_intersect( $array_metaValue, array_map('strtolower', $search_res ) ) );
        }

        // Get Percentage of each array result.
        $percent=($key/$search_count)*100;
        $percent=round($percent,0);
        ?>

        //html part
    } // for each close
```

Now I want to `ORDER BY` or show my result according to `$percent` variable then after show the results. I can't use the `$percent` var in my SQL statement. What should I do.

This is how it is displaying right now. I want the 400% to the top.
[image]

Comment: are you using `$post` and `$percent` only to display the results in html ? or you need the other variables in the html output

Comment: this `<?php echo $percent."%";  ?>` and this `$wpjobus_resume_picture = esc_attr(get_post_meta($id, 'wpjobus_resume_profile_picture',true));` I am using in the html

Comment: Im using `$percent` and `$id` in the html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Order the results using PHP [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

```
     <?php

     $mygetting_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT post_id,meta_value from wp_postmeta Where meta_value  LIKE '".$search_res[$k]."%' OR meta_value  LIKE '%".$search_res[$k]."%'  AND meta_key='my_profile_tags' ORDER BY post_id $limit");

     $sortedResults = array(); 

     foreach ( $mygetting_id as $post )
     {
      $id = $post->post_id;

     $metaValue= esc_attr(get_post_meta($id, 'my_profile_tags',true));
     $array_metaValue = explode(',',$metaValue);
     $array_metaValue = array_map('strtolower', $array_metaValue);
     $total_tags=count($array_metaValue);//like total=10

     for($e=0;$e<=count($search_res);$e++)
     {
         $key = count( array_intersect( $array_metaValue, array_map('strtolower', $search_res ) ) );
     }

     // Get Percentage of each array result.
     $percent=($key/$search_count)*100;
     $percent=round($percent,0);

     // adding percent property to use it in usort
     $post->percent = $percent;

     $sortedResults[] = $post;
     }

    // sorting results
    usort($sortedResults, function($a, $b){
       // in case if they are equal
      if($a == $b) return 0;
      return $a->percent < $b->percent ? 1 : -1;
    });
    /// now your results are sorted do html part
    foreach($sortedResults as $post){
      // do your html here e.g
      echo $post->id;
      echo $post->percent . '%'; // etc
    }

    ?>
```

or you can store percentage as separate field in the table and just `ORDER BY` score

Comment: I reply back in 10 mins. i am trying your answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use complex arithmetic operations in ORDER BY.

So, use the following.

```
$mygetting_id = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT DISTINCT post_id,meta_value from wp_postmeta Where meta_value  LIKE '".$search_res[$k]."%' OR meta_value  LIKE '%".$search_res[$k]."%'  AND meta_key='my_profile_tags' ORDER BY 


round(($key/$search_count)*100)


 $limit");
```

Comment: how can I use this in sql? I am getting the $key and $search_count var in the foreach loop.

Comment: Execute this sql in loop.

Comment: @Pupil You're missing OP's point. $key and $search don't exist before the query is run.

Answer (score 1):

You could use jQuery to re-order them.

```
<div id="parent">
   <div>1</div>
   <div>2</div>
   <div>3</div>
   <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Apply this on a `$(document).ready();` or `load();`

```
var list = $('#parent');
var listItems = list.children('#parent>div');
list.append(listItems.get().reverse());
```